What did Donne mean when he referred to “Counsell Tables“?
John Donne, Sermon XIV:

The University is a Paradise, Rivers of Knowledge are there, Arts and Sciences flow from thence. Counsell Tables are Horti conclusi, (as it is said in the Canticles) Gardens that are walled in, and they are Fontes signati, Wells that are sealed up; bottomless depths of unsearchable Counsels there.

What does Donne mean here with "Counsell Tables"?

From the examples seen on searching for the term, it is almost certainly an official forum for the making of important political/religious decisions. As with committees, smallish groups would sit around a table.

More recently the term is used for tables in courtrooms, where counsels to the parties in a case sit. The meaning of counsel for legal adviser or representative goes back to the 15th century if not further. Cambridge University's law school was well-established by Donne's time, but did they have tables? Here's a reference to counsel tables in the 18th century which is a bit later. Knowing more of the context would help but I can only find a limited-view copy of the sermons on Google Books.

Thank you very much. I should think Donne was using the term in a more general sense; your remarks and Edwin Ashworth’s are useful though.
